# On pdf export LyX document is incomplete

Tags: errors, lyx

As noted above the lower sections of the document seem to be cut off. The sections seem to be considered to be on the "last" page of the document but in reality they should continue to flow to the next page. The table of contents still shows them, and it looks fine in HTML export... But PDF and DVI end at page 7 incorrectly. Also I notice that after section 4.5 (the last bit of typing before it is just skeleton) it adds an extra page and a half of whitespace.. I tried removing different parts of the document but to no avail. Here is the source(Sorry for "censoring" a little of it.. but it shows the problem all the same)

```
% Preview source code

%% LyX 2.0.7 created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=2cm,bmargin=2cm,lmargin=2cm,rmargin=2cm}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[unicode=true,pdfusetitle,
 bookmarks=true,bookmarksnumbered=false,bookmarksopen=false,
 breaklinks=false,pdfborder={0 0 1},backref=false,colorlinks=false]
 {hyperref}

\makeatletter

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% LyX specific LaTeX commands.
%% Because html converters don't know tabularnewline
\providecommand{\tabularnewline}{\\}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\title{Project Scope \& Feature Set}

\maketitle

\part{Document Purpose \& History}


\section{Document Purpose}


\paragraph{The purpose of this document is to provide a high level overview
of features to be developed during the build phase of the project.
At this time the document should not contain any references to look
\& feel or to the access levels required to use select functionality.
Those belong in the Design \& Feature Placement documents respectively.}


\section{Team Members}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline 
Role & First Name Last Name, Initials & E-Mail Address\tabularnewline
\hline 
Document Owner & {*}{*}{*}{*} & {*}{*}{*}{*}{*}\tabularnewline
\hline 
Editor & {*}{*}{*}{*} & {*}{*}{*}{*}{*}\tabularnewline
\hline 
\end{tabular}


\section{Document History}

\begin{tabular}{|c|>{\raggedright}p{10cm}|c|}
\hline 
Editor & Change & Date\tabularnewline
\hline 
{*}{*}{*} & Completed public home page requirements round 1 & February 4th, 2014\tabularnewline
\hline 
{*}{*}{*} & Initial Document Creation - Purpose \& Team Member segments completed. & February 4th, 2014\tabularnewline
\hline 
\end{tabular}

\newpage{}

\tableofcontents{}

\newpage{}


\part{Feature Requirements}


\section{Public Home Page}


\subsection{Process}

There is no process for the public home page. It is a stand alone
page with no pre-requisites.


\subsection{Entry Points}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Direct Linking from one of the following places:

\begin{enumerate}
\item Search engine results
\item Browser bookmark
\item Referal from another user
\item Ad click
\item Referal from another site
\end{enumerate}
\item Website Banner or Navigation Home Button click.
\item User logout button click.
\end{enumerate}

\subsection{Exit Points}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Browser tab or window close.
\item Loss of power.
\item URL change via user input.
\item Browser back button click.
\item Navigation menu click.
\item Footer link click.
\item User search executed. (\nameref{sec:User-Search-Results})
\item {*}{*}{*}{*} search executed.
\item User authentication executed.
\item User registration button click. (\nameref{sec:User-Registration})
\item User profile button clicked.
\item Promotional user clicked.
\item Promotional {*}{*}{*}{*} clicked.
\end{enumerate}

\subsection{Fields}
\begin{enumerate}
\item All header fields @see Site Chrome:Fields
\item All user search fields @see User Search:Fields:Basic
\item All {*}{*}{*}{*} search fields @see {*}{*}{*}{*} Search:Fields:Basic
\end{enumerate}

\subsection{Requirements}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Render the header and footer according to the requirements laid out
in @see Site:Chrome
\item Render the user search form according to the requirements laid out
in @see User Search:Basic
\item Render the {*}{*}{*}{*} search form according to the requirements
laid out in @see {*}{*}{*}{*} Search:Basic
\item Render the search results according to the requirements laid out in
either @see User Search Results:Basic or @see {*}{*}{*}{*} Search
Results:Basic depending on the user's last executed search.
\item Render promotional users based on some criterion. Criterion TBA.
\item Render promotional {*}{*}{*}{*}s based on some criterion. Criterion
TBA.
\end{enumerate}

\section{User Registration\label{sec:User-Registration}}


\subsection{Process}


\subsection{Entry Points}


\subsection{Exit Points}


\subsection{Fields}


\subsection{Requirements}


\section{Authentication\label{sec:Authentication}}


\subsection{Process}


\subsection{Entry Points}


\subsection{Exit Points}


\subsection{Fields}


\subsection{Requirements}


\section{User Profile\label{sec:User-Profile}}


\subsection{Process}


\subsection{Entry Points}


\subsection{Exit Points}


\subsection{Fields}


\subsection{Requirements}


\section{User Dashboard\label{sec:User-Dashboard}}


\subsection{Process}


\subsection{Entry Points}


\subsection{Exit Points}


\subsection{Fields}


\subsection{Requirements}


\section{{*}{*}{*}{*} Creation\label{sec:censored-Creation}}


\subsection{Process}


\subsection{Entry Points}


\subsection{Exit Points}


\subsection{Fields}


\subsection{Requirements}


\section{{*}{*}{*}{*} Profile\label{sec:censored-Profile}}


\subsection{Process}


\subsection{Entry Points}


\subsection{Exit Points}


\subsection{Fields}


\subsection{Requirements}


\section{{*}{*}{*}{*} Dashboard\label{sec:censored-Dashboard}}


\subsection{Process}


\subsection{Entry Points}


\subsection{Exit Points}


\subsection{Fields}


\subsection{Requirements}


\section{User Search\label{sec:User-Search}}


\subsection{Process}


\subsection{Entry Points}


\subsection{Exit Points}


\subsection{Fields}


\subsection{Requirements}


\section{User Search Results\label{sec:User-Search-Results}}


\subsection{Process}


\subsection{Entry Points}


\subsection{Exit Points}


\subsection{Fields}


\subsection{Requirements}


\section{{*}{*}{*}{*} Search\label{sec:censored-Search}}


\subsection{Process}


\subsection{Entry Points}


\subsection{Exit Points}


\subsection{Fields}


\subsection{Requirements}


\section{{*}{*}{*}{*} Search Results\label{sec:censored-Search-Results}}


\subsection{Process}


\subsection{Entry Points}


\subsection{Exit Points}


\subsection{Fields}


\subsection{Requirements}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't think* the problem is severe.  Once you add some actual text to these sections, LyX will be able to find suitable page-breaking points.  Try adding some text at the start of section 5 (User Registration) to check.  (*Note: I don't have LyX installed.)

Comment: As @jon says, the problem is that TeX is unable to find a suitable place for page breaks when you only have (sub)section headings. If you look at the last PDF page, you may see that the headings continue into the bottom margin and off the page. Also, I think you've used `\paragraph` wrong. It is a heading, similar to `\section`, it doesn't indicate a text block.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick responses... I'm trying to figure out how to mark this question as "answered" but I'm new here and I don't see any option.